# How to turn 3 .py files into 1 .exe file

Tags: python, compilation, pyinstaller

I am making my own programming language called sapphire and I want to turn it into 1 exe file. but it has 3 py files. How would I achieve this? Preferably using pyinstaller.

Comment: What happened when you used pyinstaller?

Comment: i did `pyinstaller --onefile shell.py basic.py strings_with_arrows.py` and my PC crashed

Answer (score 1):

If your main file has dependancies pyinstaller will import all these files if you use:

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

Comment: shell.py links to basic.py which links to strings_with_arrows.py

Comment: so you should try pyinstaller --onefile shell.py and it will import basic.py and strings_with_arrows.py